# Filtering Datagridview through Checklistbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview and i just want to filter it from the checklistbox checked items..Some one please help me. Thanks

Example:
this is my table
**PROJECTID DESCRIPTION ...**
1                        A
2                         B
3                         C
4                         D

and my checklistbox are bind with the column "description".
I checked a and b from the checklistbox and I want to populate my datagridview based on the checkeditems from the checklistbox. Sorry for my bad english. Any solutions?

Comment: Use the CheckChanged (or similar on the check box you are using)  event to build/rebuild the filter on the datasource for the DataGridVew.

Comment: can you give me sample codes? :) tnx